# OffsetTime.parse causes an exception with ISO_TIME formatter

Tags: java, time-format

I am trying to convert between LocalTime and strings by using the ISO_TIME formatter, but I get an exception. My Code is like:

```
        LocalTime some_time = LocalTime.of( 10, 10, 10 );
        String time_format = some_time.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_TIME);
        System.out.println(OffsetTime.parse(time_format, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_TIME ));
```

the last line throws an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '10:10:10' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain OffsetTime from TemporalAccessor: {},ISO resolved to 10:10:10 of type java.time.format.Parsed
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.createError(DateTimeFormatter.java:1920)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1855)
    at java.time.OffsetTime.parse(OffsetTime.java:327)
```

Why is this happening and how could I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance for any help,
Anas

Comment: What do you want an `OffsetTime` for? Asking out of curiosity because, while I have used it once, I generally have a hard time figuring out whether it has got any good and meaningful use.

Comment: Actually, I am using it just because I have to provide a prameter to a method that I cannot control its signature and it expects OffsetTime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because, well, it's right there in the name. An `OffsetTime` contains both an actual time (such as '5 minutes past midnight') as well as a zone offset, such as '+01.00'. (as in, in some location that is currently 1 hour later than UTC time, such as mainland europe in the winter).

in contrast, a `LocalTime` contains only an actual time, not an offset.

Converting from a local time (be it in string form or as a `LocalTime` object) to an OffsetTime is therefore not possible; OffsetTime has no idea which offset you'd want.

What you can do is something like this:

```
LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse("10:10:10", DateTimeFormatter.ISO_TIME);
OffsetTime atPlus1 = time.atOffset(ZoneOffset.ofHours(+1));
```

Here you get the time from the string, and then programmatically set the offset.

Let me repeat: the string `10:10:10` fundamentally is not an offset time. You can convert that string to an offset time as well as you can convert an apple into a banana.